# Generating admin config

Tags: magento-1, configuration, admin

We keep finding demand for modules that transfer a batch file to or from a remote location. Rather than create redundant code, we thought it would be a good idea to create a sharable module for handling file transfer mechanisms. But we only got as far as a little bit of helper code before we realized that we would have to code the config fields into each "user module" (what we call the modules that use the FileTransfer module). There're multiplying points-of-failure there because each config field that has to be created can be different from the others.

What we really need is a way consistently to generate the needed admin config fields.

1. Generating actual XML seems like the wrong thing to do.
2. In our team we discussed creating custom frontend_models in the FileTransfer module, and that's the direction we're headed in now, but that will require us to manually code all the widgets and everything for the frontend and handle the POST specially in the backend. All of that seems unnecessary since we're just trying to duplicate procedures that Magento does anyway.

What we want is to guarantee config consistency across any module that uses a component of the FileTransfer module. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the configuration fields generic, or specific to each website?

Comment: @Toast they're mostly generic. I suppose it'd be nice to be able to customize some of the helper fields, but not required.

Answer (score 3):

You can create admin configuration values with a system.xml file in your modules `/etc/` folder.  This is an example from [Magento's wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <sections>
    <EXAMPLE translate="label">
      <label>An Example Section</label>
      <tab>general</tab>
      <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
      <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </EXAMPLE>
  </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: The question is about how to programmatically generate the effect, not how to just create them once.

Comment: By placing the code in the system.xml file, it will automatically be included anytime the module is installed.  Dynamic fields aren't required (see the answer's comments).

Comment: This *looks* like an example of an ordinary `system.xml` from any module that adds fields to `core_config_data`. But what I need is to have one module whose `core_config_data` fields are cloned and renamed by other modules.

Comment: I think you could use the `Mage_Core_Model_Config` class in a setup script to to get the data, then auto-generate your XML file.  That comes with it's own challenges and likely isn't the best way.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to extend the config model (or by association, add fields to the admin config) through PHP.

I've just done a quick dive into the config model to check things out.  It doesn't dispatch any events and it doesn't extend anything that dispatches events.  I also drilled through a few of its methods to see what it does when it's parsing the XML files... well, that's all it does.  It doesn't hit any other objects that might be able to inject nodes into it.

Short of modifying core code, which you must absolutely not do, it doesn't look like you can programmatically add admin config fields.  So, it seems like the less-than-ideal solution you're currently working towards is your only real option, sorry to say.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to change them through the gui? If not, you can just add a configuration setting for each transfert, like:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <namespace>
            <fileTransfer>
                <user-module1>
                    <from>http://my-domain.com/my-file.csv</from>
                    <to>ftp://other-domain.com/new-file.csv</to>
                </user-module1>
            </fileTransfer>
        </namespace>
    </default
</config>
```

This way, you can access the configuration via `Mage::getStoreConfig('namespace/fileTransfer')` and this returns an array. Every element in the array is an array with the keys `from` and `to`

So you can just add new nodes `<user-module2>`, ... If you coded your file transfer module generic, you can add all kind of URIs, like `file://`, `php://`, `ftp://`, etc.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear – when I talked about "admin config" I was talking about the GUI.

Comment: Then I think the way should be to implement your own renderer in the backend to show th pairs to and from, adding a little bit js to add new input fields and generating different xml config nodes while saving.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up writing [a Magento extension](https://github.com/eBayEnterprise/magento-active-config) to make it easy to inject configuration.

It's fairly involved, but the idea is that another module, by observing an ActiveConfig event, can supply config fields to many different modules. For example, we use it in [Magento File Transfer](https://github.com/eBayEnterprise/magento-file-transfer). See the [config.xml](https://github.com/eBayEnterprise/magento-file-transfer/blob/master/src/app/code/community/EbayEnterprise/FileTransfer/etc/config.xml#L33) where the event handler is registered, and the main [injector implementation](https://github.com/eBayEnterprise/magento-active-config/blob/master/src/app/code/community/EbayEnterprise/ActiveConfig/Model/Injector.php) for how data ends up in config.